# Rspec not running on an application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, rspec, tdd

Ok so I am a ruby on rails developer and I am about to start trying to use the TDD (test driven development) approach and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I have an existing app that has some rpec tests already and I am trying to figure how to run them but when i do

```
rake spec
(in /Users/tamer/Sites/preview)
/Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/aws-s3-0.6.2/lib/aws/s3/extensions.rb:206:in `const_missing_from_s3_library': uninitialized constant PreviewsController (NameError)
    from /Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/backward_compatibility.rb:20:in `const_missing'
    from /Users/tamer/Sites/preview/spec/controllers/previews_controller_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:386:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:386:in `map'
    from /Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:386:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:18:in `run'
    from /Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:55:in `run_in_process'
    from /Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:46:in `run'
    from /Users/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@my_app/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10:in `block in autorun'
rake aborted!

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Is there something that i am missing and what I need to do to get the previous tests to run

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is pretty self-explanatory.

```
uninitialized constant PreviewsController (NameError)
```

Chances are the `PreviewsController` class referenced by `./spec/controllers/previews_controller_spec.rb` no longer exists in `/app/controllers`.

Either update the spec or remove it if the corresponding controller has been removed.